# C# форматированный вывод

Tags: c#

Требуется, что бы число N выводилось согласно: целая часть числа в разбивне пробелом на тысячи, миллионы, миллиарды ...

Пример:

N = 1000000,0001 => out: 1 000 000,0001

Вопрос: как это сделать, есть ли что-то встроенное или изобретать велосипед?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8ztz0sa(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для решения вашей задачи нужно использовать строки форматирования. Также, следует добавить локаль, если ваш поток не гарантированно имеет правильную локаль:

```
N.ToString(format)
```

или

```
var ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU");
N.ToString(format, ci)
```

Вопрос в том, какую взять форматную строку.

[Стандартная форматная строка `N`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-numeric-n-format-specifier) *почти* подходит вам: она выводит целую часть разделённой на части согласно вашей локали, но она обрезает число на `ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits`, где `ci` — ваша явно или неявно указанная локаль.

```
1000000.0001.ToString("N") == "1 000 000,00"
```

Если вы вместо этого попытаетесь использовать `N18`, то в конце числа будут выводиться незначащие нули:

```
1000000.0001.ToString("N18") == "1 000 000,000100000000000000"
```

Поэтому вам придётся использовать [настраиваемую форматную строку](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings). Для ваших целей подойдёт `"#,0.##################"`, которая включает разделители тысяч (`,`), десятичную запятую (`.`) и опускает незначащие нули (`#`):

```
1000000.0001.ToString("#,0.##################") == "1 000 000,0001"
```

---

Не забывайте, что в других локалях используются другие разделители:

```
1000000.0001.ToString("#,0.##################", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")) ==
    "1,000,000.0001"
```

Кстати, форматную строку можно использовать не только в `ToString`, но также и в `string.Format`, и в интерполируемых строках.