# Как сделать деление числа типа double на разряды?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сталкиваюсь с большими числами, начиная с тысячи и заканчивая 10 миллионами.

Как можно сделать разделение чисел на разряды, чтобы, например, 10000 выводилось, как 10К (для удобства)?

**Код:**

```
public Text cashText;
public double cash;

void Update()
{
    cashText.text = cash + "$"; //текст, показывающий сколько игрок накликал долларов
}



public void Click () //метод, прибавляющий 500$ за нажатие
{
    cash += 500;
}
```

Comment: А на разряды-то делить зачем? для описанной задачи...

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону string format. А в целом можно закинуть условие. Если кол-во денег больше 1000, то вывод равен cash/1000 + "K". В целом от этих советов можете отталкиваться и развивать их в нужную вам сторону.

Comment: Мммм... Где на ru so был прямо точный дубликат этого вопроса (типа [такого](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3758606/5752652)) - про детект кило, мега и прочее, но сходу могу предложить только разбивать по 1000 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/904721/213987 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/802301/213987

Comment: блин, Artik Slayer, спасибо, как же я сам не додумался, а ведь это выход и даже, кажется, очень легкий выход, нужно попробовать

Comment: Деньги в `double` :(. Используйте `decimal`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Спасибо за идею @Artik Slayer и @V-Mor за ответ. Я думаю, что проще будет сделать так

```
 void Update()
 {
 if (cash >= 1000)
    {
        double fakecash = cash/1000;
        cashText.text = System.Math.Round(fakecash, 2) + "k" + " $";
    }
    if (cash >= 1000000)
    {
        double fakecash = cash/1000000;
        cashText.text = System.Math.Round(fakecash, 2) + "m" + " $";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю простое решение (по сути, является адаптацией комментария [@Artik Slayer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/180600/artik-slayer)):

```cs
public Text cashText;
public double cash;
public string[] prefixes = new string {"", "K", "M", "G"}

void Update()
{
    int prefixNumber = 0;
    while((cash / 1000) > 1)
        prefixNumber = setPrefix(prefixNumber)

    cashText.text = cash + prefixes[prefixNumber] + "$"; //текст, показывающий сколько игрок накликал долларов
}

public int setPrefix(int num)
{
    cash = cash / 1000;
    return ++num;
}



public void Click () //метод, прибавляющий 500$ за нажатие
{
    cash += 500;
}
```

Это далеко от идеала, но удовлетворяет поставленным требованиям.

Что здесь происходит:

1. Объявляется массив приставок: без приставки (если значение меньше 1000), кило-, мега-, гига- (далее можно продолжить в зависимости от предполагаемых значений)
2. Проверяется значение переменной `cash`
3. Если значение больше тысячи, номер добавляемой приставки наращивается, а значение уменьшается в тысячу раз
4. При выводе к числу добавляется нужная приставка

P.S. Запустить код у себя не имею возможности, так что заранее прошу прощения за возможные синтаксические ошибки.

Comment: Нет контроля на переполнение - исключение IndexOutOfRange

Comment: @nick_n_a Я же говорю, код далёк от идеала. Целью ответа было показать 
сам принцип, а не предоставить качественный безопасный код. В данном случае следует делать массив такой длины, которой заведомо будет достаточно для всех возможных значений переменной.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать что то типа такого

```
private static string[] arr = new[] { string.Empty, "K", "M" };
string Format (double number)
{   
    if (number < 0) return "-" + Format(-number);
    if (number < 1000) return number.ToString();
    var ind = Math.Min(arr.Length - 1, (int)Math.Log(number, 1000));
    var ret = number / Math.Pow(1000, ind) + arr[ind];
    return ret;
}
```

Проверка

```
Console.WriteLine(Format(0));
Console.WriteLine(Format(1));
Console.WriteLine(Format(123));
Console.WriteLine(Format(12345));
Console.WriteLine(Format(1234567));
Console.WriteLine(Format(123456789));
Console.WriteLine(Format(-123));
Console.WriteLine(Format(-12345));
Console.WriteLine(Format(-1234567));
Console.WriteLine(Format(-123456789));
```

Вывод

```
0
1
123
12.345K
1.234567M
123.456789M
- 123
- 12.345K
- 1.234567M
- 123.456789M
```